# How to identify my Windows 8.1 partition(s)

Tags: linux, partitioning, windows-8.1

I have a home assembled desktop computer with Windows 8.1 installed. I have previously had Windows Vista Business 64 installed and I remember experimenting with Ubuntu some time ago (dual boot).

I can see 4 partitions, where the largest of course is my Windows 8.1 primary partition:

[image: Windows partition view]

Using the application [*MiniTool Partition Wizard*](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) I get the following informations, stating that the remaining partitions are `EXT4`, `EXT3` and `Linux Swap`:

[image: MiniTool Partition Wizard view]

**Question:**
I want to clean up the partitions and would like to know if I can safely assume that the three small partitions has nothing to do with my Windows 8.1 installation? I don't need my Ubuntu partitions and would like to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't use nor even recognize ext or Swap partitions, you can delete them safely.

Remember that deleting partitions won't give you more space, you'll have to create a new one in place of those three and format it in a format recognized by Windows - NTFS will probably be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll delete them and extend the primary partition. [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read) allowed me to see the contents of the `EXT3` and `EXT4` partitions and they looked like a set of `Linux` partitions.